# MVC Fist Load Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project with a page where the user does search (dropdown,checkbox,input...).
Id like to load empty model at first time the page is request because the model contains several records.

How can i tell to controller that is first request and load empty data ?

Comment: The first thing that it comes to me is to not trigger the search functionality on page load but on another event (let's say when the user pushes the search button)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how...could you explain with code example

Comment: Could someone help me?

Comment: Put some code here in order to be easier for someone to help you

Answer (score 0):

i forgot my class for view

```
public class FatturePagedList
{
 public IEnumerable<FatturaView> PagesFatture {get;set;}
 public IEnumerable<string> Distinzione {get;set;}
}

public class FatturaView
{
public int Anno {get;set}
public string Distinzione {get;set;}
public decimal Importo {get;set;}
ecc...
}
```

I hope it is all.